# How Process Size is determined?

Tags: c, operating-system

I am very new to these concepts but I want to ask you all a question that is very basic I think, but I am confused, So I am asking it.
The question is...
How is the size of a process determined by the OS? 
Let me clear it first, suppose that I have written a C program and I want to know that how much memory it is going to take, how can I determine it? secondly I know that there are many sections like code section, data section, BSS of a process. Now does the size of these are predetermined? secondly how the size of Stack and heap are determined. does the size of stack and heap also matters while the Total size of process is calculated.

Again we say that when we load the program , an address space is given to the process ( that is done by base and limit register and controlled by MMU, I guess) and when the process tries to access a memory location that is not in its address space we get segmentation fault. How is it possible for a process to access a memory that is not in its address space. According to my understanding when some buffer overflows happens then the address gets corrupted. Now when the process wants to access the corrupted location then we get the segmentation fault. Is there any other way of Address violation.

and thirdly why the stack grows downward and heap upwards.Is this process is same with all the OS. How does it affects the performance.why can't we have it in other way?

Please correct me, if I am wrong in any of the statement.

Thanks
Sohrab

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a process is started it gets his own virtual address space. The size of the virtual address space depends on your operating system. In general 32bit processes get 4 GiB (4 giga binary) addresses and 64bit processes get 18 EiB (18 exa binary) addresses.

You cannot in any way access anything that is not mapped into your virtual address space as by definition anything that is not mapped there does not have an address for you. You may try to access areas of your virtual address space that are currently not mapped to anything, in which case you get a segfault exception.

Not all of the address space is mapped to something at any given time. Also not all of it may be mapped at all (how much of it may be mapped depends on the processor and the operating system). On current generation intel processors up to 256 TiB of your address space may be mapped. Note that operating systems can limit that further. For example for 32 bit processes (having up to 4 GiB addresses) Windows by default reserves 2 GiB for the system and 2 GiB for the application (but there's a way to make it 1 GiB for the system and 3 GiB for the application).

How much of the address space is being used and how much is mapped changes while the application runs. Operating system specific tools will let you monitor what the currently allocated memory and virtual address space is for an application that is running.

Code section, data section, BSS etc. are terms that refer to different areas of the executable file created by the linker. In general code is separate from static immutable data which is separate from statically allocated but mutable data. Stack and heap are separate from all of the above. Their size is computed by the compiler and the linker. Note that each binary file has his own sections, so any dynamically linked libraries will be mapped in the address space separately each with it's own sections mapped somewhere. Heap and stack, however, are not part of the binary image, there generally is just one stack per process and one heap.

The size of the stack (at least the initial stack) is generally fixed. Compilers and/or linkers generally have some flags you can use to set the size of the stack that you want at runtime. Stacks generally "grow backward" because that's how the processor stack instructions work. Having stacks grow in one direction and the rest grow in the other makes it easier to organize memory in situations where you want both to be unbounded but do not know how much each can grow.

Heap, in general, refers to anything that is not pre-allocated when the process starts. At the lowest level there are several logical operations that relate to heap management (not all are implemented as I describe here in all operating systems).

While the address space is fixed, some OSs keep track of which parts of it are currently reclaimed by the process. Even if this is not the case, the process itself needs to keep track of it. So the lowest level operation is to actually decide that a certain region of the address space is going to be used.

The second low level operation is to instruct the OS to map that region to something. This in general can be

- some memory that is not swappable
- memory that is swappable and mapped to the system swap file
- memory that is swappable and mapped to some other file
- memory that is swappable and mapped to some other file in read only mode
- the same mapping that another virtual address region is mapped to
- the same mapping that another virtual address region is mapped to, but in read only mode
- the same mapping that another virtual address region is mapped to, but in copy on write mode with the copied data mapped to the default swap file

There may be other combinations I forgot, but those are the main ones.

Of course the total space used really depends on how you define it. RAM currently used is different than address space currently mapped. But as I wrote above, operating system dependent tools should let you find out what is currently happening.

Answer (score 2):

The sections are predetermined by the executable file.

Besides that one, there may be those of any dynamically linked libraries. While the code and constant data of a DLL is supposed to be shared across multiple processes using it and not be counted more than once, its process-specific non-constant data should be accounted for in every process.

Besides, there can be dynamically allocated memory in the process.

Further, if there are multiple threads in the process, each of them will have its own stack.

What's more, there are going to be per-thread, per-process and per-library data structures in the process itself and in the kernel on its behalf (thread-local storage, command line params, handles to various resources, structures for those resources as well and so on and so forth).

It's difficult to calculate the full process size exactly without knowing how everything is implemented. You might get a reasonable estimate, though.

W.r.t. `According to my understanding when some buffer overflows happens then the address gets corrupted.` It's not necessarily true. First of all, the address of what? It depends on what happens to be in the memory near the buffer. If there's an address, it can get overwritten during a buffer overflow. But if there's another buffer nearby that contains a picture of you, the pixels of the picture can get overwritten.

You can get segmentation or page faults when trying to access memory for which you don't have necessary permissions (e.g. the kernel portion that's mapped or otherwise present in the process address space). Or it can be a read-only location. Or the location can have no mapping to the physical memory.

It's hard to tell how the location and layout of the stack and heap are going to affect performance without knowing the performance of what we're talking about. You can speculate, but the speculations can turn out to be wrong.

Btw, you should really consider asking separate questions on SO for separate issues.

Comment: thanks...I will keep that in mind next time...:-)...thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

*"How is it possible for a process to access a memory that is not in its address space?"*

Given memory protection it's impossible. But it might be *attempted*. Consider random pointers or access beyond buffers. If you increment any pointer long enough, it almost certainly wanders into an unmapped address range. Simple example:

```
 char *p = "some string";

 while (*p++ != 256)  /* Always true. Keeps incrementing p until segfault. */
     ;
```

Simple errors like this are not unheard of, to make an understatement.

Comment: Thanks! I don't entirely hate to learn this kind of terminology :-)

Answer (score 0):

I can answer to questions #2 and #3.

**Answer #2**

When in C you use pointers you are really using a numerical value that is interpreted as address to memory (logical address on modern OS, see footnotes). You can modify this address at your will. If the value points to an address that is not in your address space you have your segmentation fault.

Consider for instance this scenario: your OS gives to your process the address range from 0x01000 to 0x09000. Then

```
int * ptr = 0x01000;
printf("%d", ptr[0]); // * prints 4 bytes (sizeof(int) bytes) of your address space
int * ptr = 0x09100;
printf("%d", ptr[0]); // * You are accessing out of your space: segfault
```

Mostly the causes of segfault, as you pointed out, are the use of pointers to NULL (that is mostly 0x00 address, but implementation dependent) or the use of corrupted addresses.

Note that, on linux i386, base and limit register are not used as you may think. They are not per-process limits but they point to two kind of segments: user space or kernel space.

**Answer #3**

The stack growth is hardware dependent and not OS dependent. On i386 assembly instruction like push and pop make the stack grow downwards with regard to stack related registers. For instance the stack pointer automatically decreases when you do a push, and increases when you do a pop. OS cannot deal with it.

**Footnotes**

In a modern OS, a process uses the so called logic address. This address is mapped with physical address by the OS. To have a note of this compile yourself this simply program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a = 10;
    printf("%p\n", &a);
    return 0;
}
```

If you run this program multiple times (even simultaneously) you would see, even for different instances, the same address printed out. Of course this is not the real memory address, but it is a logical address that will be mapped to physical address when needed.